# Is it possible to read from a pivot table using java program?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I would like to know if it's possible to read the pivot table using any existing APIs such as POI. I know there are some limitations regarding reading / changing the values of the cell, but I want to know at which extent we can read the sub content of the cell?

Has anyone tried this before? Are the documentations of POI V3.13 updated on this topic?

I see a lot of questions about pivot table creation, but not reading.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can read existing PivotTables in XLSX workbooks using [XSSFSheet.getPivotTables()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getPivotTables()).

If the XSSFPivotTable class doesn't have the methods you need, consider developing the functionality that you need and contribute back the patches for the new code, unit tests, example code, and/or documentation.

The [latest documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/) is generated from the trunk.